# POE with Arduino Leonardo Eth

Tags: power, ethernet, arduino-leonardo

I recently purchased a [Leonardo Eth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013PUTJYO) and a [5v POE module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AMBBJJW) in an attempt to have a POE micro-controller.  I installed the module in the holes closest to the Ethernet jack side of the board, but when I apply power, the green power light turns on every second or so, but never fully turns on.

What am I doing wrong? Did I install the module wrong? Is it the wrong module?

Comment: So you have PoE injector with 36V to 72V power supply? (I suppose 48V ones are most common as 24V is out of range for your PoE Module)

Comment: I have a PoE 48v 802.3 af switch

Comment: Have you verified that your terminations on the cable are good, and you are getting the necessary voltage at the Arduino end of the cable?  Once that is verified, check the output pins of the POE module, verify the necessary voltage, and if possible, hook a scope up to it, and watch what is happening.

Comment: POE switch and cable work fine, as I can power other POE stuff with it.  I measured the output voltage of the device and it was very unstable.  I think I will just buy a different module.

Answer (score 2):

From the arduino.cc website.

"The optional PoE module is designed to extract power from a conventional twisted pair Category 5 Ethernet cable. PoE module features are as follows: IEEE802.3af compliant Input voltage range 36V to 57V Overload and short-circuit protection 12V Output High efficiency DC/DC converter: typ 85% @ 80% load 1500V isolation (input to output)"

It sounds like you need the 12V PoE module